# fprintf is not working properly in Visual Studio (C programming)

Tags: c, visual-studio, file

I was working with files in visual studio (2015 professional) when I got to this problem

take a look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a;
    FILE* H = fopen("data.txt", "w+");
    if (fgetc(H) == EOF)
    {
        fprintf(H, "A");
        fseek(H, 0, SEEK_SET);
    }
    if (( a = fgetc(H)) == 'A')
    {
        fprintf(H, "B");
    }
    fclose(H);
}
```

The problem was that "A" was being written on data.txt file, but B was not.
I tried running the code on debug mode. It went to the second "if" and then reached fprintf(H, "B") but still no luck and B wasn't being written on the file. The next thing I did was to check out the return value of fprintf, so I tried this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        char a;
        int err;
        FILE* H = fopen("data.txt", "w+");
        if (fgetc(H) == EOF)
        {
            fprintf(H, "A");
            fseek(H, 0, SEEK_SET);
        }
        if (( a = fgetc(H)) == 'A')
        {
            err = fprintf(H, "B");
        }
        fclose(H);
    }
```

The err was showing 1 as the return value of fprintf(H, "B") but the only thing that was being written on data.txt was still A. what I've anticipated out of this code was:

1. data.txt to be created
2. fgetc to read EOF (since there is nothing written on the file yet it is true)
3. A to be written
4. pointer to be moved to start of file (behind A in the file)
5. in the second if "A" to be read by fgetc and pointer of the file to be moved one character forward
6. At the end B to be written after A in the data.txt file

Well... all of that happened except the last one. I reached out to people who were using different compilers other than visual studio However, for them, this code was working perfectly fine, and the result was "AB" being written on the file.
Later on when I used fseek to move the pointer of file it pretty much solved the problem, but I'm still wondering why it didn't work without fseek being involved, logically everything looks fine to me though I'm not sure why its not working in visual studio.
(by the way for those who seek the fix with fseek :) here's the code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a;
    int err;
    FILE* H = fopen("data.txt", "w+");
    if (fgetc(H) == EOF)
    {
        fprintf(H, "A");
        fseek(H, 0, SEEK_SET);
    }
    if ((a = fgetc(H)) == 'A')
    {
        fseek(H, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        err = fprintf(H, "B");
    }
    fclose(H);
}
```

Comment: What if you `fflush` after the first `fprintf` ?

Comment: I run the first code on my machine and it printed `AB` to `data.txt`. For you the first code print just `A` to the file? does it print newline or anything else? or just one charachter, `A`, and thats it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. you meant like `fflush(H);` between the fprintf and fseek right? if so it didn't work

Comment: @GalBirka did you use visual studio to run your code? and to answer your question yes it just prints `A` and thats it

Comment: OT:  regarding: `FILE* H = fopen("data.txt", "w+");`  after calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `char a;` and `if (( a = fgetc(H)) == 'A')`  The function: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: @user3629249 regarding the return value of `fgetc()` you can check this [site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgetc.htm#:~:text=Return%20Value,end%20of%20file%20or%20error.) which confirms that the return value of `fgetc()` is a `char` data type

Comment: The link clearly says `int fgetc(FILE *stream)` and the example shows `int c;`. The C library almost *never* uses a `char` type for a single character.

Comment: "We don't usually check that a file pointer `!= NULL` after opening a file." Where are you getting your information? You should *always* check that the file opened. When you start making assumptions about what *should* happen with I/O you have very weak  code.

Comment: @WeatherVane you are right, let me rephrase myself **I** don't usually check my `fopen`s when I'm opening my files in `w` or `w+` mode and I know where I'm doing it although I did many tests before posting this problem and one of them actually was to check the `fopen` for if its `NULL` and that wasn't the case at all, what I've brought up in my question was only a handful of tests that I did. I'm fully aware of how weak this code is and that was not my intention to present a strong code, I made the simplest code I could to point out what I've wanted to ask, thank you for warning me about that

Comment: @WeatherVane and @user362949  I made a mistake about that, the site states that "This function returns the character read as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int` or `EOF` on end of file or error." which at first led me to believe that the return value of `fgetc` was actually a char data type,  you are correct about that, although when I was testing the program defining `a` as a `char` kind of benefited me and wasn't problematic (atleast for me) because I could watch the actual character behind `a` and didn't need to look for ASCII code of what I was watching. Thank you both

Comment: I noticed that too. If one byte in the file has value `0xC0` that is an `unsigned char` value 192 not the -64 which the (typically signed) `char` would be. So as `int` that is 192 and not -64. Another reason for `int` being returned is so that the caller can distinguish the byte value `0xFF` from the flag value `-1`. It is not normally a problem with an ASCII text file because the text values are `< 128` anyway, but it's worth getting into good habits.

Comment: I believe what you've said is truly important and could even be another question and be answered by what you've stated. Thank you for noting that, and yes sir it definitely is.

Answer (score 3):

C18 § 7.21.5.3 says (my bolding)

> 7 When a file is opened with update mode (’+’ as the second or third character in the above list of mode argument values), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek, fsetpos, or rewind), and **input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function**, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.

This is why the writing of `"B"` after reading `'A'` did not work correctly, and adding `fseek()` in accordance with the C standard, allowed it to work.